# Quadratic and linear constraints in Mosek (from Matlab)

Tags: matlab, mosek

I have a question regarding how to run a quadratically constrained  minimisation problem in Mosek (from Matlab). This is my problem

[image]

**Suppose that the linear equality and inequality constraints are not there.** The Mosek documentation ([here](https://docs.mosek.com/9.1/toolbox/tutorial-qo-shared.html)) explains well how to implement the optimisation problem. First, we should rewrite the problem as

[image]

Second, we should set

```
clear prob;

% Specify the linear objective terms.
prob.c      = [0, -1, 0];

% Specify the quadratic terms of the constraints.
prob.qcsubk = [1     1    1   1  ]';
prob.qcsubi = [1     2    3   3  ]';
prob.qcsubj = [1     2    3   1  ]';
prob.qcval  = [-2.0 -2.0 -0.2 0.2]';

% Specify the quadratic terms of the objective.
prob.qosubi = [1     2    3    3  ]';
prob.qosubj = [1     2    3    1  ]';
prob.qoval  = [2.0   0.2  2.0 -1.0]';

% Specify the linear constraint matrix
prob.a      = [1 1 1];

% Specify the lower bounds
prob.blc    = [1];
prob.blx    = [-3;-3;-4];
prob.ulx    = [3;3;5];

[r,res]     = mosekopt('minimize',prob);
```

**Question: how can I introduce in the code above the two linear equality and inequality constraints in my example?**

I have tried to look at examples on linear programming but they do not seem to easily mix with my code above.

Comment: prob.a must have more rows and blc/buc must be longer, one new row per each linear constraint, like in the linear optimization example in the manual.

Comment: thanks. How does `prob.a` know that the first row is referred to the quadratic constraint and the others to the linear constraints?

Comment: qcsubk indicates in which row each quadratic term should appear

Comment: thanks. Can I set `prob.a` equal to a sparse matrix?

Comment: Yes, in fact sparse is preferred.